# Write one value to an SQL table from vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, ado.net

From within my VB.Net program, I would like to write to one specific column of a row in a table in an SQL database, given the row's primary key.  What is the lowest-overhead means of doing this?  I understand how to create a table adapter, fill a datatable, write to the datatable and then update the database.  Is there a relatively simple way to directly access the database table instead?

Comment: Do you mean you want to update the field in the tbl for an existing row with the given primary key?

Comment: Update/write to the field of a row specified by the row's primary key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to access a database in VB.NET is going to be to use a [SqlCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.aspx) object combined with a [SqlConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.aspx).  Even that is going to require 5-7 lines of code to do anything from your perspective, but if you want to get any thinner/simpler than that you're typically going to have to start looking into ORMs or data wrapper classes.

Answer (score 2):

If it really is that simple - create a SqlCommand with a sql update statement.

The solution is simple, efficient and requires very little code overhead. However it is definitely not recommended for larger applications as it will be a pain to maintain in larger scale.